# Bootstrap website broken in IE11 only on high dpi screens

Tags: internet-explorer, retina-display, highdpi

I'm having a really weird problem of the website displaying *significantly* differently in IE 11 on standard resolution screens to IE 11 on high resolution screens.

At standard res, it's working perfectly - looks the same as other browsers, and nothing broken.

At high res, it's completely borked. Not even a little bit off, 100% broken.

This is all on Windows 10, in case that's relevant. I know Windows 8.1+ tries to sort out high dpi issues with automatic scaling, but this seems to be beyond that.

The website is made with Bootstrap, so already using prefixes to handle partial support for IE 11 for flexbox, etc.

I tried setting maximum and minimum sizes in the viewport meta, ie: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">` This did not show any improvement.

I also whacked on Compatibility Mode just to see - it renders differently, but still broken.

I know IE 11 is legacy and I don't usually support it, but the client is specifically asking. Has anyone come across a similar situation to this? Is it fixable at all, or would you just take a stern line with the client to make them update / reassure them that basically nobody uses IE 11 on high dpi screens?

[High res screenshot](https://www.adzoo.com.au/new-choice-ie-11-high-res.jpg) 
[Low res screenshot](https://www.adzoo.com.au/newhome.png)

Edited to add screenshots.

Comment: Can you please show us the picture of the site looks like on HD monitor and also let us know about the steps or any sample code to produce the issue. It will be hard for us to assume the issue from only your description. Check whether zoom is applied. Try to check the display setting of Windows 10 and try to adjust the screen resolution to check whether it helps to solve the issue for IE or not.

Comment: If it is possible for you than can you please try to share the address of the site? We will try to visit the site and try to test the issue. It can help us to see the actual code and we can check it through developer tools to check the applied styles on it.

Comment: The site in question is [newchoicehomes.com.au](https://newchoicehomes.com.au/)

Comment: Thanks for providing the URL of the problematic site. I will try to find any high dpi screen and try to produce the issue. I will try to search for any possible solution for this issue and try to inform you soon. Thanks for your understanding.